# Angular 9 - Prevent url change

Tags: angular

I have a web page in Angular 9. Some views have elements list and we can show all details of this elements clicking in a icon and redirecting to another view passing id in the url. This is may a security errors because some elements only can view by some roles, others roles cannot access to them. Actually all roles can change URL manually and access all elements.

I try to prevent URL change manually but i don't find the correct way.

Somebody know how i can ignore manual URL changes?

Comment: It's not possible to prevent the users from changing the URL manually. But you can use a guard to check whether those users can access that component with that id in the URL and redirect them to a safe URL in case they don't have enough permissions to access it. Just use a router guard to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way here is using `Guard` & [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) in your `app-routing.module.ts`. You have to implement a `role-based Guard` to check the users `Authorizations` and based on that allow user or prevent it from visit a specific path. The best way is check the `Roles` and `Access Permissions` based on the stored data in user `Token` if you use `JWT` ob server-side app.

So, by this way if a user doesn't have the access to visit a `Component` or a `path` your `Guard` will prevent him and can be redirected to a specific `path` even if he/she change the `URL` manually.

For more information here is a useful article:
[Router Guards](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to your question, and also an additional consideration.

**Additional Consideraton**

The additional consideration, is that a user can navigate to URL's, regardless of whether you present them with the option to navigate their naturally. In other words, I don't need a link to be present, in order to actually type in a given url, such as
`www.ishouldnotbeabletoaccessthisforexample.com`

So in order to account for this, you must implement some [routing guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) to evaluate if a url can be accessed / loaded / activated (depending on your purpose and implementation). So for instance, what CanActivate does, is when you attempt to visit a url, it evaluates a condition that you set out within this CanActivate method. If it returns true, you can access the url and its contents. If it evaluates false, then you cannot access the contents. You can also opt to redirect them here. So consider that you should implement that, regardless of the answer below.

**Answer to your Question**

The easiest solution to implement, is to filter your list of URLS depending on an authorization condition, set by you.

So for example:

```
accessLevel = 0;
listOfUrls = [
  {url: 'www.example.com/canVisitHere', accessLevel: 0},
  {url: 'www.example.com/admin/cantVisitHere', accessLevel: 1}
] as ILink[]; // In this example, ILink is a simple interface, built by you requiring url, and accessLevel. Maybe optional? text or icon also.

// Constructor or wherever you want to evaluate your URLS
constructor() {
  this.accessLevel = this.getAccessLevel(); // Or use subject instead
  this.listOfUrls = this.listOfUrls.filter(x => x.accessLevel <= this.accessLevel); // If using a subject above, place this logic inside of your subscribe response
}
```

This would stop an inaccessible link from even displaying on the page in the first place, which is what you should be doing from a usability / UX standpoint.